# Django Celery periodic task example

Tags: python, django, celery

I need a minimum example to do periodic task (run some function after every 5 minutes, or run something at 12:00:00 etc.).

In my `myapp/tasks.py`, I have,

```
from celery.task.schedules import crontab
from celery.decorators import periodic_task
from celery import task


@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(hour="*", minute=1)), name="run_every_1_minutes", ignore_result=True)
def return_5():
    return 5


@task
def test():
    return "test"
```

When I run celery workers it does show the tasks (given below) but **does not return any values** (in either terminal or flower).

```
[tasks]
  . mathematica.core.tasks.test
  . run_every_1_minutes
```

**Please provide a minimum example or hints to achieve the desired results.**

**Background:**

I have a `config/celery.py` which contains the following:

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.local")

app = Celery('config')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

And in my `config/__init__.py`, I have

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

I added a function something like below in `myapp/tasks.py`

```
from celery import task

@task
def test():
    return "test"
```

When I run `test.delay()` from shell, it runs successfully and also shows the task information in flower

Comment: How do you run worker? Do you use -B option: `celery -A proj worker -B` ?

Comment: like this, `celery -A config worker -l info`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run periodic task you should run celery [beat](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#starting-the-scheduler) also. You can run it with this command:

```
celery -A proj beat
```

Or if you are using one worker:

```
celery -A proj worker -B
```

Comment: Should I run `celery -A proj worker -l info` and `celery -A proj beat` on two separate terminals? I did the same and run flower using `celery -A config flower`. Waiting for five minutes and nothing seems to happen (either in terminals or flower)

Comment: `test.delay()` from shell still works and updates are shown on terminal and flower. However, the periodic task is not running. Any help?

Comment: @Inquilabi yes, you need to run them both. Do you see in beat terminal `run_every_1_minutes` task executed?

Comment: No. My beat terminal looks like, `LocalTime -> 2018-05-25 21:55:15
Configuration ->
    . broker -> redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%WARNING
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
`

Nothing else is shown.

Comment: Yes. I did. Had redis been not running, task.delay() would have not run.

Comment: Received 'PONG' for 'redis-cli ping'.

Comment: The issue was resolved by replacing `run_every=(crontab(hour="*", minute=1))` by `run_every=(crontab(minute="*/1"))`